# Add Web Service to Existing App

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic-10.x

I have a web app deployed as an ear in WebLogic 10.0 and need to expose some functionality as a web service to be called by a .NET app.  Can someone point me to some WebLogic docs or a good tutorial on this?  The examples I found in the WebLogic docs show how to create a new web service and deploy but not how to add one to an existing app.

Answer (score 1):

I'd write JAX-WS wrapper around your functionality.

Check [Suns tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/) or hit google with "jax-ws tutorial".

JAX-WS are standard Java 6 SE Webservices and are easy to handle.